# Selection sort. What's wrong?

Tags: python, sorting, selection-sort

```
def selectionSort(alist):
    for bottom in range(len(alist)-1): 
        min_idx = bottom
        for idx in range(bottom+1, len(alist)):
            if alist[bottom] > alist[idx]:
                min_idx = idx
        alist[bottom], alist[min_idx] = alist[min_idx], alist[bottom]
    return alist
```

This is the python code to implement selection sort, but it does not give me a correct result.

```
print(selectionSort([2,4,5,1,23,5,4,43,12])) 
> [1,2,4,4,12,5,5,23,42]
```

What's wrong with it?
Thank you all.

Comment: Please provide sample input and output. Also a description of why the output is wrong.

Comment: You’re comparing `alist[bottom] > alist[idx]` but it should be `alist[min_idx] > alist[idx]`.

Comment: print(selectionSort([2,4,5,1,23,5,4,43,12])) gives me [1,2,4,4,12,5,5,23,42]

Comment: @Ryan Thank you so much! I understood what I did wrong.